# Filter array of objects based on object's value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array with several objects within. I want to retrieve the object with the property called `types`, which is an array, having an entry called "zoom". Here is what the array of objects looks like:

```
[Object, Object, Object]
0: Object
1: Object
2: Object
  exclude: "0"
  file: "/m/a/max_wind_zoom.jpg"
  position: "7"
  types: Array[1]
     0: "zoom"
```

So I want to only extract object 2 in this case since its property `types` has an entry `zoom`.

I'm really puzzled as how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

```
[Object, Object, Object].filter(function (o) {
    return o.hasOwnProperty('types') && o.types.indexOf('zoom') > -1;
})
```

Comment: Or just `return o.types && o.types.indexOf('zoom') > -1;`